# Docker named volumes in VS Code Dev container (with docker compose file)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I really liked the approach of [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/06/16/docker-development-container/) guide about setting up a **devcontainer** with **docker compose** and being able to start all the services that my project needs from *within* the dev container itself. VS Code can only handle 1 container per window so this trick is helpful. BUT.

The author uses a **named volume** (external) to copy the entire source tree of the project from the host into the container. Named volumes offer better performance than bind mounts.
The problem with this is that your project starts to become very inconsistent between your host and your devcontainer. When you switch from your devcontainer to your host project folder you cannot see the recent changes made inside the devcontainer because those changes are only available inside that named volume.

Also, the **rebuild** command (from vscode remote containers) doesn't work because the execution of this command happens in the host and the host is blind about the new changes made to the named volume. So nothing gets rebuilt.

I don't understand not only why the author doesn't talk about this (it is a big deal, you can lose any progress you made if you accidentally delete the named volume), but also the **official docs** from vscode follow the same approach ([here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance#_use-a-named-volume-for-your-entire-source-tree)):

> Finally, if none of the above options meet your needs, you can go one step further and clone your entire source tree inside of a named volume rather than locally.

Why there is no warning about this?
I'm even starting to think there's something I'm doing wrong about this setup.
I would appreciate your comments on this matter.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JJAsghar Hi. Not necessarily a code issue perse. My config files are the same as the link I provided. Should I put this in devops.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Very good question. Does anybody have some insights regarding this topic?
Did you find a solution to this problem @serranomorante?

Comment: @fabem Hi. I just ended up using bind mount volume.

```
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - ./local_directory:/app

```

But this approach doesn't let me control the docker service from within my devcontainer. So, I have to execute docker commands from the host's terminal.

Comment: I would like to figure this out as well. Have you made any progress @serranomorante? I am wondering if it would be possible to bind mount repo into /workspace-bind, then copy it to /workspace on container launch and the use some tool to keep the disks in sync in a way that wil not be too demanding. I am not sure.